# MySQL not using Index to Sort

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have read over several other stack overflow questions about this now and it's still not making sense.

I'm experimenting with the sakila world test database, here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `CountryCode` (`CountryCode`),
  KEY `city_name` (`Name`),
  CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country` (`Code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4080 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

here are my indexes:

```
mysql> show index from City;
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| City  |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | ID          | A         |        4188 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| City  |          1 | CountryCode |            1 | CountryCode | A         |         465 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| City  |          1 | city_name   |            1 | Name        | A         |        4188 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I am trying to understand why MySQL is not using the index to sort results here:

```
mysql> explain select * from City order by Name asc;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | City  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4188 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

I do not understand why MySQL is doing a filesort in this case, it's pretty obvious that the index on the City name has everything sorted already.

I looked in some other questions, people were using prefixes in their index, which was forbidding MySQL from using that index to sort.  I did not use a prefix when I created that index on name.

Also other people were expecting to see "Using index" in the Extra column.  My understanding is that means the index 'covered' the query, meaning that the actual table did not need to be read since the index had all the values.  So I am not expecting to see that in the Extra column because the index is on the name alone, and there are other columns.

I feel like that term "Using index" is a bit misleading, MySQL could use an index to filter results but still have to read the table.  In that case, "Using index" would not be part of the Extra column.  Too misleading.

Can somebody please explain to me why MySQL is still using a filesort for that query?  There are 4079 rows in case you want to know.

Also, is there any clear way to know that MySQL used an index to sort results?

Comment: The optimizer sees you are going to read all records from the table, so it prefers reading from PRIMARY index instead of the secondary  city_name . Thus MySQL has to do additional sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select *
from City 
order by Name asc;
```

There are two parts to this query.  One part is getting the name values in the right order.  The other part is fetching all the other columns.  MySQL has to compare the cost of these two operations.

There are two possible paths for the query.  The first is to take all the columns and sort them by name.  Then just return the results.  This is the filesort method.  The second is to read the index in order, and then lookup the rows one-by-one in the datatable.

MySQL has decided that the first method is faster.  This would obviously be true if you only had one row (why read an index *and* the row when you can just read the row?).  My guess is that you have very little data in the table.  As you add more data, the use of the index will be more beneficial.

As a note, this query should generally use the index method:

```
select Name
from City 
order by Name asc;
```

Comment: how many rows does it take for MySQL to decide it's better to use the second method?  I already have over 4000 rows in the table.  So you are saying that sorting 4000 rows takes less time than fetching rows from an index.

Comment: Consider sorting any set of 4000 keys with some optimized sort. The time is negligible. Transfers from disk are far more expensive (consider you need to transfer both the index structure and the table rows). There is no set number however, it all depends on heuristics based on statistics and design. 4000 rows is an absolutely tiny number rows, all things considered.

Comment: @msknapp . . . 4,000 seems big enough for MySQL to use the index.  Question:  Why are you using `char()` values rather than `varchar()`?  The fixed length records are larger and may be throwing off the optimization decision.

Comment: @Gordon, like I said in the question, I imported the data from the sakila test database, I didn't make it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you don't decide to filter the results (i.e. no where clause), the RDBMS will decide to use a sort/filter approach (as opposed to the index) for a reason you mention above. Your attempting to return all the information pertaining to all of the rows in your table, which is simply more efficiently accomplished without using the index given that in order to return data that is additional to the indexed column, a look up and transfer must be done against the table, once the key is found in the index.

In other words, the index is built on the field you have chosen, but doesn't contain any of the other relevant information about the table... Ergo, it must refer back to the true location of the table to retrieve that additional metadata you have requested, which is less efficient that simple sorting the records (given that you have such a small data set). The reason for this is that it is faster CPU wise to sort a small data-set on your (name) column than it is to retrieve values based of your index, and then sort them.

Often however, indexes aren't used when retrieving a high-volume of wide-records from a table of an arbitrarily large size for the exact reason I mentioned. You can given the planner hints that will force it to use an index to verify what I've mentioned here... You can also grow your data-set by some large factor and then attempt to select a smaller portion of it to test my theory.